# Set a condition on an email being sent from an sql database

Tags: mysql, email

I need to send an email to anyone who has a 0 in the submitted column of a database. The database table that has the email currently has a "conditions" column that looks something like this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM sc_application WHERE candidate_id = $user_id
```

Is there a way to add the condition of "if submitted = 0 is true" then send the email?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Kermit Sorry, I am quite new to this. I need to send an email to anyone who has a 0 in the submitted column of a database. The database table that has the email currently has a "conditions" column that looks something like this: SELECT first_name, last_name FROM `sc_application` WHERE candidate_id = $user_id . Is there a way to add the condition of "if submitted = 0 is true" then send the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tack on another conditional to the end of your query:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name FROM sc_application WHERE candidate_id = $user_id AND submitted = 0
```

Comment: That's it eh? Thank you very much. I will give it a try and see what happens. I am still so new to this side of things.